# How to set android button shadow instead of setting text shadow

Tags: android, button, shadow

I'm trying to set a shadow for my button, but instead of getting shadow for the whole button I'm getting it for button's text only.

I've tried both: using xml styles

```
<style name="shadowed_button">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#444444</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">9</item>
</style>
```

and setting shadow programmatically

```
button.setShadowLayer(9, 1, 1, Color.rgb(44, 44, 44));
```

Both work identically.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so you have to make the image of the button with shadow and place on the button as drawable.

Comment: Thanks. I've already thought about that. I was just curious if there are any other more elegant ways of doing that.