# How to make shadow effect for abutton in android?

Tags: android

I'm using `android:shadowDx` and `android:shadowDy` .. for a text and they work fine,  can I use it for button or any other view ? if No , how may I make shadow effect for a button ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[android:shadowcolor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:shadowColor) is a TextView's property, only applicable to Text. There is also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401684/how-to-set-android-button-shadow-instead-of-setting-text-shadow) an earlier post for your question.