# How to provide shadow to Button

Tags: android, material-design, shadow

[image]

As you can see in image, I want shadow behind a `Button`. I have created `Button` with rounded corners. But problem is I can't generate a shadow behind that `Button`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567312/android-drop-shadow-on-view & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563927/how-to-make-shadow-effect-for-abutton-in-android

Comment: That could be useful too, for realistic shadows with different colors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583069/how-to-put-shadow-with-gradient

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use this approach to get your desired look.
**button_selector.xml :**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#D6D6D6" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
            <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="270" 
                    android:endColor="#E2E2E2" android:startColor="#BABABA" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA" />
                <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" 
                    android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

</selector>
```

**And in your xml layout:**

```
<Button
   android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
   ...
   ..
/>
```

Comment: This looks cool, but when I tried this intellij didn't like it. When I looked at the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for `item` it says `android:drawable` is **required**.

Comment: closing </selector> tag is missing

Comment: It's not exactly what the asker wanted as this solution makes the opposite: gradient button background and solid shadow color. And this seemes very different from outer shadow

Comment: Can I make it so that a textColor selector is baked into the above selector -so I don't have to set both background textColor each time I define a button, but only needs to set the background...?

Comment: `<selector>` and `<item>` are not needed. The image is reverted, as @user4702646 said.

Comment: the bottom corner left has a hard edge

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? It looks no where near the desired shadow

Comment: This results in a non(well, barely)-gradated shadow, because the gradient is applied not just to the visible shadow part but the entire offset shape.

Answer (score 71):

***For android version 5.0 & above***

try the [Elevation](http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html) for other views..

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

For Buttons,

```
android:stateListAnimator="@anim/button_state_list_animator"
```

**button_state_list_animator.xml** - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/anim/button_state_list_anim_material.xml

***below 5.0 version,***

For all views,

```
 android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: I'd like to use this approach, but my buttons are created dynamically (i.e. in code) in a grid control, not declaratively (actually, I'm using Xamarin free version, so Mono lib). Doesn't seem to be a straightforward method to set just any attribute.

Comment: @jrichview see this answer & also comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/24459128/3879847

Comment: Hey, how can I use this as drawable, if I set the shape of my button with drawable?

Answer (score 24):

**Here is my button with shadow** `cw_button_shadow.xml` **inside** `drawable` **folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list>
            <!-- SHADOW -->
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@color/red_400"/>
                    <!-- alttan gölge -->
                    <corners android:radius="19dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- BUTTON alttan gölge
              android:right="5px" to make it round-->
            <item
                android:bottom="5px"
                >
                <shape>
                    <padding android:bottom="5dp"/>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="#1c4985"
                        android:endColor="#163969"
                        android:angle="270" />
                    <corners
                        android:radius="19dp"/>
                    <padding
                        android:left="10dp"
                        android:top="10dp"
                        android:right="5dp"
                        android:bottom="10dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <!-- SHADOW -->
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#102746"/>
                    <corners android:radius="19dp"/>

                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- BUTTON -->
            <item android:bottom="5px">
                <shape>
                    <padding android:bottom="5dp"/>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="#1c4985"
                        android:endColor="#163969"
                        android:angle="270" />
                    <corners
                        android:radius="19dp"/>
                    <padding
                        android:left="10dp"
                        android:top="10dp"
                        android:right="5dp"
                        android:bottom="10dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**How to use. in Button xml, you can resize your height and weight**

```
<Button
                android:text="+ add friends"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
               android:background="@drawable/cw_button_shadow" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

If you are targeting pre-Lollipop devices, you can use [Shadow-Layout](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/shadow-layout), since it easy and you can use it in different kind of layouts.

**Add shadow-layout to your Gradle file**:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.shadow-layout:library:1.0.1'
}
```

**At the top the xml layout where you have your button, add to the top**:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

*it will make available the custom attributes.*

**Then you put a shadow layout around you Button**:

```
<com.dd.ShadowLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:sl_shadowRadius="4dp"
        app:sl_shadowColor="#AA000000"
        app:sl_dx="0dp"
        app:sl_dy="0dp"
        app:sl_cornerRadius="56dp"> 

       <YourButton
          .... />

</com.dd.ShadowLayout>
```

You can then tweak the `app:` settings to match your required shadow.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Poor lib, with deprecations, plus no more supported. Besides, it seems like it allows only for dark / black shadows, not light ones.

Answer (score 11):

I've tried the code from above and made my own shadow which is little bit closer to what I am trying to achieve. Maybe it will help others too.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
                    <gradient
                        android:angle="315"
                        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:startColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:type="radial"
                        android:centerX="0.55"
                        android:centerY="0"
                        android:gradientRadius="300"/>
                    <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="0dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="3dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />


                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Please, attach a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

Try this if this works for you

[image]

```
android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
```

Comment: This is actually the most accurate answer. Unfortunately trying to get a designer to work with 9-patch isn't an easy thing.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the below 2 lines worked for me

```
android:elevation="10dp"
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 1):

[Sample 9 patch image with shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TIwf.png)

After a lots of research I found an easy method.

Create a 9 patch image and apply it as button or any other view's background.

You can create a 9 patch image with shadow using this [website](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/).

Put the 9 patch image in your drawable directory and apply it as the background for the button.

```
mButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.your_9_patch_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the answers here really address the question, I wanted to point out https://github.com/Devlight/ShadowLayout (not my project). This is a simple Android layout you can wrap around anything to give it a shadow. The library is a single class and only ~250 lines. The README says deprecated, but it works great.

Wrapping all your views isn't ideal, but until Android provides a standard mechanism to introduce a shadow, or you want to draw all of your button states as bitmaps that include the shadow pixels, this is the best option I could fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
<layer-list>
        <item android:left="1dp" android:top="3dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#a5040d" />
                <corners android:radius="3dip"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp">
            <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#99080d" />
                <corners android:radius="3dip"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:bottom="3dp" android:right="2dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#a5040d" />
                <corners android:radius="3dip"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.