# Android: how to add shadow to App Widget

Tags: android, layout, imageview, shadow, android-appwidget

and thank for your help.

I have an App Widget with the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/borderimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linear"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/linear"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/linear"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/linear"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/box" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linear"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/linear"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/linear"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/linear"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/gradient_box" />
```

As you can see I use two ImageView on top of the layout to create a background and a border

- backgroundimage is the background
- borderimage is the border

(I need to do this way because the background and the border needs to be changed at runtime).

I would like to add a shadow, to get an effect like this: 
[image]

Any suggestion more than welcome!
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button

Answer (score 0):

For some widgets that come with a transparent background you can use a background color that is partially transparent, it won't drop a shade but create a similar effect.
for example for SeekBar widget use `android:background="#55000000"`