# Android studio- Adding style to buttons

Tags: java, android, xml, button, styles

I want to add a shadow and have rounded edges on my button, like box-shadow and border radius in CSS how can I do this in XML? 
XML code:

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
    style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="198dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/dummy_button"
    android:fontFamily="trebuchet ms"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="printStarter"
    android:background="#8c96ff"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Developer's Guide has a detailed guide on this: Shape [Drawbables.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#1a1a1a" />
```

**button with shadow**

```
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/shadow"/>
   <item
     android:drawable="@drawable/button"
     android:bottom="4px" /> 

</layer-list>
    </shape>
```

Refer this [tutorial](http://belencruz.com/2012/12/rounded-button-with-shadow-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML, here are some links:
[How to provide shadow to Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button) ; 
http://zrgiu.com/blog/2011/01/making-your-android-app-look-better/ . OR
You can use a 9patch image: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html