# Shadow surround the button with the use of custom style

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, styles

[image]

I would like to create a button like the "default button" refered to the image. Here is my code , the problem is that it doesn't like a shadow but a solid border. How to fix it? Thanks

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#000000" />

        <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#811E19" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: You should use a 9 patch.

Comment: REad here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button

Comment: so, what about put background image for button?

Comment: Read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape The stroke property is to set the border

Comment: Thanks. stroke is more like a border than a shadow