# What technology used for designing Google inbox UI

Tags: android, user-interface

I know its a very general question but I really keen to know and want to develop an android application with special UI (I mean a professional UI like Google Inbox app).

I just wanted to know if there is a special sort of technology used in it or it just made by relative layout and linear layout and other android UI component which known in Android SDK with java.

any kind of clue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Identifying the technologies used in third-party programs is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific strange technology but some principles. please take a look at this:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#introduction-goals

it may give you some ideas.

Comment: thank you this is what exactly I mean by Inbox UI but its html5 I think... is it possible to combine it with java in eclipse? I mean html5 UI and Java backend?

Comment: Actually after watching your link  and a little searching , I found that android material is designed for lollipop (v 5.0) . but I have seen apps with this style which works correctly in android 2.3 and above. how is this possible?

Comment: @MGol yes Actually material design is for lolipop But you can have all those features in lower apis. thats just a little difficult and it needs to be implemented by the developer himself from scratch.

Comment: So how can I do? for example all those complex animations and other stuff.. is that possible?

Comment: as I told you you can have what ever you want for example for drop shadow you can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button and for other stuff just do some searches on SO you'll find them. ;)

Comment: Thank you Mr Milad,  have you seen "Abrak" Application?? it has so much visual effects which I think it should be implemented somehow easier than what you mentioned. can you please help me to know how?

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at that. please give me the download link.

Comment: here you can download it : http://myket.ir/App/com.omid.abrak/%D8%B4%D8%A8%DA%A9%D9%87-%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%AA%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%A9

Comment: I saw it. everything they used is with java. i'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

The design language you're seeing is called **Material Design**.

The user interface elements that it may be using are **`RecyclerView`** for storing a list of information and **`CardView`** to represent individual items in the list:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView/>
```

Have a look at this https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html on how to cook up such an activity (a screen in Android).

The theming your application is not too difficult. Have a look at https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

[image: material design tutorial]

Comment: tnx dear @jay your answer was really helpful. just do you have any project sample by material design like Google inbox which can help me to go through it?

Comment: I just found [**saulmm/RecyclerView-demo**](https://github.com/saulmm/RecyclerView-demo). It looks to have a very good overview of what each class required does.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly Google is doing some cool things, and they make good use of their own platform, but I don't believe there are major special technologies they are using just for their own apps. They just put together view hierarchies, nice animations, and nice resources, to make it look good.

Was there a particular aspect you are wondering about?

Comment: Thank you Bruce but my question was about material design in lower android versions. do you know how?