# Using one style on several buttons with different background images

Tags: android, xml, android-button, android-styles, android-background

Hi I am trying to style several buttons in one menu with the same size and shadow,
I found code here [How to provide shadow to Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button) to help me do this but I want each button to have a different background image but as I am already calling this style using          `android:background="@anim/button_menu"` I cannot change the background of each button by saying `android:background="@drawable/imageclassroom"` as background has already been called. Any help on how to overcome this issue would be great

Answer (score 1):

use this tyep make a color button

```
 <Leniarlayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_hight ="40dp"
 android:background ="#000"
 android:padding ="5dp">

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/angry_btn"
 android:text="Button"
 android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
 android:textSize="30sp"
 android:layout_width="270dp"
 android:layout_height="60dp"
 android:background="@drawable/(set image path)"
 android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
 android:shadowDx="0"
 android:shadowDy="0"
 android:shadowRadius="5"
 />
 </Leniarlayout>
```

Comment: thats cool but doesn't solve my problem, I am trying to apply a style to several buttons but also change the background of each button so that they all look different

Comment: what type of style u want

Comment: all buttons should have curved corners with a shadow behind them and shadow behind the text, then each button will have a different image as the background

Comment: all you are saying is great except I don't know how to set the button background as an image

Comment: android: background = "@drawable/image.file

Comment: yes but I cant use that and andorid:background="drawable/ the xml file    as there is two android:background which is not allowed

Comment: edit your image in use Photoshop customize size example :60x30 pixel

Comment: btn backgroud using image file k shadow btn using put the bellow code in button  android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
 android:shadowDx="0"
 android:shadowDy="0"
 android:shadowRadius="5"

Comment: What you are saying adds the shadow to the text in the button not the other edge of the button

Comment: Yes that adds shadow to the text I want shadow on the outside of the button not the text just the button

Comment: use above code create linear-layout set shadow background on linear-layout put button on linear-layout