# how to add background shadow effect for button programmatically in android

Tags: android

I am using `Button` in a `Service` class. The `Button` is working fine. I just want to know how can I add some background shadow effects for button. Is it possible to add background shadow effect for button programmatically in android?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button

Comment: @user1841702 yaa I have already tried but it is not giving me good shadow effect

Comment: use `View#setBackground` with a `LayerDrawable`

Comment: @pskink layerDrawable means the drawable which contains shadow animation code?

Comment: animation? what animation? `LayerDrawable` should contain "real" button and the "shadow" in the second layer

Comment: OK thanks I got it:)