# How to create an image button with raise effect?

Tags: android

I have some Button with background that support press state and normal state but raise effect remove when i set background for it.
How to enable raise effect with background?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are calling raised is actually known as elevation in android devlpment enviroment terms. You can set the elevation for the view in the XML like below

```
android:elevation="4dp"
```

NOTE : This was introduced from API 21 lollipop.