# Android ImageButton in Material Design shows no shadow

Tags: android, material-design, android-imagebutton

I can't display the material design shadow under any component of my layout, I can't understand why.

Android minimum sdk is 21, `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">`, and if for example I add a FabButton its shadow works properly according to its elevation parameter. But not for my ImageButton or any other component.

Its layout is:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/btnMain_description"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_yellow"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

[image: The result with no shadow]

I also already tried to set a background different than @null, nothing changes, no shadows. What's going on? Which way my I have my elevation shadow on layout components?

Comment: try this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the `android:background="@null"` not just change. When ImageView has BG as null, you'll not see the shadow. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow) answer.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick, and adding 
        `android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"`
has a much more beautiful visual  effect. (thank you @pcgali-android)

Answer (score 1):

try this   remove `android:background="@null"` from your image button

```
   <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/btnMain"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:contentDescription="@string/btnMain_description"
     android:elevation="10dp"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:scaleType="centerInside"
     android:src="@drawable/btn_yellow"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```