# Button drop shadow on all sides in Android

Tags: android, xml

I would like to make my button shadow look like this:
[image: Desired shadow]

So far i tried several approaches, e.g. with a layer-list and a gradient, but i wasn't really successful so far.
Does anyone know how to achieve this? Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Filter"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Header"
        android:textColor="#15e4be"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_info"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add new xml file in drawable like that.
Step 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="23dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="13dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="18dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#3F51B5"
        /> </shape>
```

Step 2:
Use your layout.xml like that

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_cancel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorViewTextColor"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:background="@drawable/your_added_drawable"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                />
```

Done.
You need to change your_added_drawable.
Solid, Corner bla bla bla
Edit 1: android:drawableLeft your icon, you have to add drawable