# How to make UI shadow to any view

Tags: android, xml, ui-design

thank you for answering me
I just want to know how i can make the shadow below this card [image]

I already tried several ways like Elevation... but it didn't work for me.
I searched a lot about it and I found that website :
[Shadow generator](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/)

But i'm wondering if there is another way, using xml or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You are half right in that elevation is required for a shadow effect.But note this is only applicable to view that are not buttons. For buttonViews you can add a statelist animator that handles the properties of a button for all its states.Also if you are using something like a textView that does not have any margins you might as well use a background to show the shadow as follows:

```
    android:elevation="30dp"
    android:background="#000"
```

For other views, this means simply adding the elevation attribute as shown above and the background is not required

This link will help:
[How to provide shadow to Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button)