# How to add shadow in android button?

Tags: android, button, imageview

I am a beginner in android and has created an app which has a button,I am using a png background in that android button as the button's background and wants to add a shadow to it using.Should I go with elevation technique or using the corner coloring technique.
Please guide me how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide shadow to Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button)

Comment: [How to provide shadow to Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button)

Answer (score 0):

For getting shadow effect on your button or views add the line  `android:elevation="8dp"` on your button(view) at layout file. Since you are new on android don't forget to search before posting a question. 
Yours sincerely

**Edited:**  for enabling the elevation parameter of the button you should also disable `stateListAnimator` property of the button by adding  `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` to your button.

Comment: i want lighter color shadow like white shadow on black background

Comment: any further help

Comment: Colored shadows are not supported natively until Android 9.0, so to get that you need to make shadows using gradients, background graphics or use a 3rd party library, like Carbon (https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon)