# How to achieve Android Button Animation with text-blurred and shadow

Tags: java, android, animation, android-styles

I want to achieve this button animation in Android. The sample below is from iOS. I want the shadow to disappear when the user clicks the button and reappear once the user releases the button.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check the answer below and let me know if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add color like the following. For example, the color name is `button_text_color.xml`. Here is the .xml file which needs to be put in the `color` folder. If the `color` folder does not exist, create one in your `res` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#50FFFFFF" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

Check that I have added 50% transparency to the white color in the pressed state. Now just add this attribute in the `Button` where it is declared.

Now you need a background drawable, to be put in your `drawable` folder. For example, let us take the name of the drawable is `button_state_list_animator.xml`. This should have the following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                    <corners android:radius="19dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="5px">
                <shape>
                    <padding android:bottom="5dp" />
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#163969" android:startColor="#1c4985" />
                    <corners android:radius="19dp" />
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#102746" />
                    <corners android:radius="19dp" />

                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="5px">
                <shape>
                    <padding android:bottom="5dp" />
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#163969" android:startColor="#1c4985" />
                    <corners android:radius="19dp" />
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Now your button construction is simple.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_state_list_animator"
    android:text="Save Changes"
    android:textColor="@color/button_text_color" />
```

Here is the screenshot from my code.

[image]

[image]

You can have the push-down animation using the [library](https://github.com/TheKhaeng/pushdown-anim-click) as well, as mentioned in an answer here.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Dude, Where is code of translate button from push to back? You have just written about text color only.

Comment: @PratikButani So did you downvote the answer for this reason? I think the question asks for shadowing the text color only. However, I have added the library in my answer as well to make it complete. You do not have that text color shadowing part in your answer as well, which makes it incomplete as well.

Comment: Where is the `text shadow` keyword in whole question? Can you check once again please?

Comment: Not `text shadow` just `text` keyword. :) Did you found?

Comment: You can put screenshot so user came to know how it will work? If you have tried this code in Android Studio.

Comment: Screenshot added. I could not add the text color change and shadow has gone effect though. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is very much close to solution my friend.

Comment: Great to know that. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the animation effect (as the code below) on the custom button when clicking on the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="0.8"
        android:duration="500"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
    </scale>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0.8"
        android:duration="500">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

set Animation on Button Click using.

```
 btn_custom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R
                        .anim.animation_btn);
                btn_custom.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        });
```

try changing alpha values as your need and see the effect.

Comment: This doesn't help my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library : [pushdown-anim-click](https://github.com/TheKhaeng/pushdown-anim-click)

## How to install:

```
compile( 'com.github.thekhaeng:pushdown-anim-click:1.1.1' ){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

## How to use:

```
Button button = findViewById( R.id.button );

PushDownAnim.setPushDownAnimTo( button, ... )
    .setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view ){
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "PUSH DOWN !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

});
```

## For Shadow:

As I saw library files, There are only three java files. He just used class to animate button. You can give shadow in your button by [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15333583/1318946). Even though I have created [issue](https://github.com/TheKhaeng/pushdown-anim-click/issues/2) You can keep watch on this.

[image: enter link description here]

For more functionality, you can visit github link.

Thank you.

Comment: As I saw library files, There are only three java files. He just used class to animate button. You can give shadow in your button by [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15333583/1318946). Even though I have created [issue](https://github.com/TheKhaeng/pushdown-anim-click/issues/2) You can keep watch on this.

Comment: Yes. I saw the library. I appreciate your effort on creating the issue, but in my case I believe it's not relevant. As I will use shadow of different colours so I will have to do it manually. The library is good though.

Answer (score 0):

Add a layout with the background as the shadow below the button. In the `button.setOnTouchListener` hide the layout when button is pressed and make it visible when released. 
However it will only work if the shadow is below.