# button shadow parameters

Tags: android, android-layout

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button) how to create a shadow for a button.
Here's what I would like to do :
[image]

And here's what I succeeded to do so far :

[image]

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
                    <solid android:color="#D6D6D6" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@color/mainBlue"/>
                    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp"
                        android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Obviously the shadow is completely different, and if you notice, it is kind of cutten in the bottom left corner and we don't see the radius. In my design software, I specified an angle, a distance, a spread and a size for the shadow. How may I control these parameters in XML so that I can faithfully reproduce the same shadow ?

EDIT : what I ended up doing is to export my design as a png file as I didn't find any way to reproduce the shadow with code :/

Comment: the other thread and the answers are 6 to 9 _years_ old. today there are completely different things possible. have you tried the MaterialButton control? it produces shadows according to google's design guidelines. here's a complete documentation with all possible stylings and xml attributes: https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons/
Class documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton

Comment: Yes I checked that. However the shadow that I want to apply to my button is slightly different than google's guidelines. I was looking for some parameters which would allow me to reproduce the same one as in my design file :/

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding elevation to the button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Make sure that you give your button a background, otherwise it won't work.