# MaterialButton shadow in material design

Tags: android, material-design

[image: Shadow with button]

I want to create a button like this in android with blue shadow in android using material design how can I create this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to provide shadow to Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button)

Comment: most "pro" way and closest/same as in material design is to use [RenderScript](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute)